# MySQL search (easy quest)

Tags: mysql, database

I want to do something like this :

```
SELECT a.titulo, b.nome
FROM fa_album a, fa_artista b
WHERE  a.titulo LIKE '%I Love you%'
Group BY a.titulo;
```

**BUT** I have to search the name of the artists which have **ATLEAST** 2 albums that contain songs that have *I love you in* the lyrics

Comment: What is your db schema and what is your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions about the column names in your tables, something like the following. Have a sub query that gets a list of the artists who have titles as required, and check that count is greater than or equal to 2. Jion that to the list of albums to get the details of the album and the list of names

```
SELECT a.titulo, sub0.nome
FROM fa_album a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b.id, b.nome, COUNT(a.titulo) AS title_count
    FROM fa_album a
    INNER JOIN fa_artista b
    WHERE  a.titulo LIKE '%I Love you%'
    GROUP BY b.id, b.nome
    HAVING title_count >= 2
) sub0
ON a.artist_id = sub0.id
WHERE  a.titulo LIKE '%I Love you%'
```